# Extending one child template into another?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a base.html file witch has two blocks from two child templates. blog.html and masthead1.html. How do I extend one child template into another?

The base.html file has:

```
{% block mastheadname1 %}{%  endblock %}
```

and

```
{%block content%}{% endblock%}
```

The masthead1.html has:

```
{% block mastheadname1 %}
<img src="{{masthead1.mast1_url}}" alt="main-image" class="responsive main">
{%  endblock %}
```

The blog.html has:

```
{%block content%}  

#some content

{% endblock%}
```

My problem is how do I include masthead1.html blocks into blog.html? Because everytime I open `http://localhost:8000/blog/` the image does not appear.

Comment: Have you tried using the `include` tag? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include

Comment: I tried but does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

at the start of `blog.html` you should put

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}  

#some content

{% endblock%}
```

Comment: It's already there,and blog.html is extending base.html,but it is not extending the block content of masthead1.html that is present in base.html